# How to replace padding with another elements padding

Tags: html, css

I have padding on a navigation container, that I would like to keep. However, when apply a `background-color` for when each list item is hovered over. The list does have a `background` of `red`, however keeps its black padding of `15px 15px`, how am i able to manipulate that to be red throughout when hovered?

```css
.nav-contain {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  15px;
}

.nav-li li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-contain">
  <div class="nav-li">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little confused as to what you're attempting to do. Each element has its own padding. You want it so that when you hover **specifically** over the **`<li>`**, the **entire** `.nav-contain` turns red?

Comment: no sorry, when you hover over any li item, specifically that li background will turn red - like a normal navigation bar does. At the moment it partially turns red, but since the container has padding, the black padding stays when hovered

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `:hover` modifier to your `.nav-contain` class that sets the background color to red as well. For example:

```
.nav-contain {
    background-color:black; 
    padding: 15px; 15px;
}

.nav-li li:hover, 
.nav-container:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

If this is not what you desire, you are going to have to structure your HTML and the element to which you are adding padding to slightly differently. For example, you could add padding to your `li` element instead of to the `div` that holds your list like you currently have.

Comment: this will just make the whole navigation container totally red, I have multiple list items. i would like just one to ( the one hovered ) to have a background color of red.

Comment: @J.Doe then you already have the functionality that you desire implemented in the code that you originally posted. Simply add padding to your `li` element, not to the `.nav-contain` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of exactly what you're asking, however, I believe I have solved your issue. The CSS `padding` property puts a box of space around your element and parent elements will increase their size to accommodate, so you should edit the `nav-li li` element's padding rather than the `.nav-contain` element.

JsFiddle here: [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt6kwwxk/)

Comment: @J.Doe No problem, happy to help!